# Storing time with milliseconds in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to store a time stamp with millisecond precision in Rails, but the value gets jacked up when I retrieve the record from the DB:

```
record.time_stamp = Time.utc(2017,1,1,1,1,1.35)
```

Check time before saving:

```
record.time_stamp.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L')
=> "01:01:01.350" 
record.time_stamp.usec
=> 350000
record.time_stamp.to_f
=> 1483232461.35
```

Save and reload:

```
record.save!
record.reload
```

Check time after saving:

```
record.time_stamp.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L')
=> "01:01:01.006"
record.time_stamp.usec
=> 6108
record.time_stamp.to_f
=> 1483232461.0061078
record.read_attribute_before_type_cast("time_stamp") // Read raw value before type casting
=> "2017-01-01 01:01:01.35"
```

Not sure what's happening here. The millisecond value stored in the DB is correct, as is the raw value before type-casting (see last line), it's just screwed up when cast back into Ruby Time.

**NOTES:**

- I realize that [Ruby Time is precise to nanoseconds, while the DB is only precise to microseconds](http://blog.solanolabs.com/rails-time-comparisons-devil-details-etc/) - but I'm just trying to save milliseconds, so that should not be a factor.
- This is not a time zone issue.

(**Specs:** Rails/ActiveRecord 4.2.6, ruby 2.3.0, Postgres 9.5.0, OSX)

---

**UPDATE:**
I just tried reproducing this issue in a new rails app with the exact same rails/ruby/postgres versions as my current app, and could not do it! And since others have also not been able to reproduce, it means this is something clearly specific to my app, and I will need to dig further to try to isolate what is causing this... Will update when I have more info.

Comment: This might be a time zone thing. Did you check the value you get against UTC timestamp ? You might be saving the time in `UTC` and retrieving it `GMT`?

Comment: @Cyzanfar - See update, same thing in UTC. (Anyway, time zones differences would not affect seconds/milliseconds right?)

Comment: Right it shouldn’t affect it... let me do some research on my end. Let me know if and when you find a solution. It’s an interesting problem.

Comment: i tried to reproduce it on my tech stack and can tell you, this is not happening on Rails 5.1.1, ruby 2.4.1, psql 9.6.3 (all running inside docker containers)

Comment: I also tried to reproduce this but couldn't! Maybe it'd help to publish a tiny app that fully reproduces this, so people can look into it?

Comment: i also couldn't reproduce this using ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.6 and the lowest pg gem minor version that works with this (0.15.1), though I didn't change the database from 9.6.3 to 9.5 yet. More information needed.

Comment: also not reproduceable with postgres 9.5.0 in ruby2.3.0 and rails 4.2.6.

Comment: Possible some other gem used causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was being caused by the [vincenty gem](https://github.com/rbur004/vincenty). Caveat emptor...

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce the issue with Rails `4.2.6` and `5.0.5` (and Ruby `2.3.1`, Postgres `9.6.4`)

```
# Gemfile
ruby '2.3.1'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'pg'
require 'active_record'

# example.rb
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection \
    adapter:  'postgresql',
    database: 'try_timestamp',
    username: 'postgres'

  connection.create_table table_name, force: true do |t|
    t.datetime :time_stamp
  end
end

time_stamp = Time.utc 2017,1,1,1,1,1.35
record     = Record.new time_stamp: time_stamp

p record.time_stamp.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L')
p record.time_stamp.usec
p record.time_stamp.to_f

record.save!
record.reload

p record.time_stamp.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L')
p record.time_stamp.usec
p record.time_stamp.to_f


# terminal command
❯ createdb try_timestamp
❯ bundle install
❯ bundle exec ruby example.rb
"01:01:01.350"
350000
1483232461.35
"01:01:01.350"
350000
1483232461.3500001
```

Could you run this example and tell whether the issue reproduces on clear rails app?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue too.

Comment: @itsnikolay Sure enough, I just tried reproducing this issue in a new rails app *with the exact same rails/ruby/postgres versions* as my current app, and could not do it! Looks like I will need to dig further to try to isolate what is causing this..

Comment: @Yarin try to debug, step by step by adding each gem from your app Gemfile in my example app Gemfile ^^. Because some gems can patch datetime for own purposes. If you won't be able reproduce it with the full list of gems, so you should start looking the issue in your code (start searching from config/initializers etc, down to trace).

Comment: That's exactly what I did- culprit found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46889747/165673. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Check the database/table time zone vs Rails time zone vs system time zone, looks like you have a 5 hours difference between what you save and what it returns, which appears to correspond to the difference between UTC and EST.

Comment: This is not a time zone issue. The question is about the discrepancy in milliseconds, not hours.

Comment: Have you tried storing the timestamp in milliseconds (*1000) and then Time.at(ts/1000) ? I have noticed too sometimes apparently random values get rounded to integers (or, well, not so much integers considering they would still have a trailing .00001 or something when cast to_f)